# Converting float to decimal in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

I have a view which needs to return type decimal for columns stored as float.

I can cast each column to decimal as follows:

```
, CAST(Field1 as decimal) Field1
```

The problem with this approach, is that decimal defaults to 18,0, which automatically rounds the float columns to 0. I would like to keep a precision of up to 12 decimal places.

However, if I do this:

```
, CAST(Field1 as decimal(12,12)) Field1
```

I get a runtime error:

```
"Arithmetic overflow error converting float to data type numeric"
```

**the float column is defined as length: 8 Precision: 53** in the table. I can not modify anything about the table.

What's the proper way to cast it as decimal w/out losing decimal precision?

Comment: My suggestion is that you stop storing data as float  as it is an inexact data type and you will get rounding errors if you do calculations on it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`12, 12` means no digits before the decimal separator: `12` digits in total, `12` of them being after the period.

Use a more appropriate range, say:

```
DECLARE @var FLOAT = 100
SELECT  CAST(@var as decimal(20,12))
```

which gives you `8` digits before the separator, or adjust it as needed.

Comment: great thanks, do you know if there is a way to format it so it only returns decimal places if there is a value? if i select from the table, it does not show the trailing 0's, but after the cast the 12 zeros ALWAYS show..

Comment: @Sonic: so what you need: to return a `DECIMAL` or format? Formatting will leave you with a `VARCHAR`.

Comment: to go along with this answer check out this link which explains it in great detail:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15