# SQL decimal points in output

Tags: sql

How do I limit the number of decimal points in my output in SQL?  I am getting the answer 427.500000 when I only want 427.5.

My code is:

```
SELECT AVG(HRLY_RATE) *36 AS 'Supervisor"s Average Weekly Salary'
    FROM WORKER
        JOIN BUILDING 
            ON WORKER.WORKER_ID = BLDG_SUP
                WHERE BUILDING.BLDG_TYPE = 'OFFICE';
```

Comment: which database you uses? it seems SQLServer. if yes, check this [Sqlserver cast decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186789/converting-float-to-decimal-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: Which dbms??????  Tag properly!!!  The answer below, won't work if you don't use SQL Server.  Tag properly so that people don't waste time giving answer for the wrong dbms.

Comment: This should be done in the display layer (web app, form, report, whatever). Leave the data as-is when getting it from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1), (AVG(HRLY_RATE) *36) )
```

Note the format - the first value(10) is the total number of digits to store.  The second(1) is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point.